# Making an HTTP request to fill AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView, that I want to populate with data brought down via an online API. I have been following this guide

http://makovkastar.github.io/blog/2014/04/12/android-autocompletetextview-with-suggestions-from-a-web-service/

Which has worked very well, however I am now trying to edit the `getFilter` method to make a HTTP request, get the data and process it. I have used Fuel https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel for this.

Currently the code I have written is:

```
public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    List<Location> books = findLocation(mContext, constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = books;
                    filterResults.count = books.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    resultList = (List<Location>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a search result for the given book title.
     */
    private List<Location> findLocation(Context context, String bookTitle) {
        List<Pair<String, String>> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new Pair<>("searchterm", bookTitle));

        Fuel.post("https://...search.php", params).responseString(new Handler<String>() {
            @Override
            public void failure(@NotNull Request request, @NotNull Response response, @NotNull FuelError error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void success(@NotNull Request request, @NotNull Response response, String data) {

                List<Location> downloaded = new ArrayList<Location>();
                try {

                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);

                    if (obj.has("success")){
                        JSONArray success = obj.getJSONArray("success");

                        for(int i = 0 ; i < success.length(); i++) {
                            Location newlocation = new Location();
                            newlocation.setLocationID(success.getJSONObject(i).getString("TermID"));
                            newlocation.setLocationName(success.getJSONObject(i).getString("UniqueTerm"));
                            downloaded.add(newlocation);
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Throwable t) {

                }


            }
            });

        return null;
    }
```

The problem with this of course is that the HTTP request is done asynchronously so the build up Array of Locations doesn't get assigned to the AutoCompleteTextView.

I am not sure of the best way to modify the code to update the AutoCompleteTextView once the request has been successful.

Comment: That's what we call mulithreading http://ideone.com/PPHi95

Comment: so make an HTTP blocking request: `kittinunf/Fuel Features [...] Support both asynchronous and blocking requests [...]`